# JavaFX maximize the size of node children

Tags: layout, javafx

I want to have squares added to a pane, and those squares maximized.

One square takes up the whole pane.
Two squares split the pane.
Three squares make it all in thirds.

When it overflows it goes to the next "row" and continues the process.

All the squares should be the same size.

Is there a way of using the standard layouts or which should I modify?

Thanks

Comment: Why would it ever overflow?  Do the squares have some kind of minimum size?  (Anyway, I believe you are looking for a TilePane).

Comment: Correct. Assume there is a minimum width of 200... TilePane for me so far shrinks the node, is there a way to avoid that like prefTileWidth(-1)? I also would have thought TilePane works the way described. Is there a standard example that does what I am discussing?

Comment: I've been playing with it for a little while, it is actually not straight-forward to do....

Comment: Alright, I think my best solution is currently to change the prefTileWidth and prefTileHeight depending on how many tiles I have.... Not too bad, it isn't elegant but it isn't a lot of code so far either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take on this problem.  I don't think it's a great solution, but at least it might help point out some techniques somebody might build on to get a better solution.  Basically the solution overrides layoutChildren() to recalculate the preferred tile size as the number of tiles or the available space changes.  I'm not sure getWidth or getHeight should really be called from layoutChildren (though it seems to work in this case).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class TilePaneSample extends Application {

    private static final Random random = new Random(42);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TilePane tiles = createTiles();

        VBox layout = new VBox(
                createControls(tiles),
                tiles
        );
        VBox.setVgrow(tiles, Priority.ALWAYS);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout, 400, 300));
        stage.show();
    }

    private TilePane createTiles() {
        TilePane tiles = new TilePane() {
            @Override
            protected void layoutChildren() {
                if (getChildren().size() > 0) {
                    setPrefTileWidth(
                            Math.floor(
                                    Math.min(
                                        Math.max(
                                                Tile.MIN_SIZE,
                                                getWidth() / getChildren().size()
                                        ),
                                        getHeight()
                                    )
                            )
                    );
                    setPrefTileHeight(getPrefTileWidth());
                }

                super.layoutChildren();
            }
        };
        tiles.setStyle("-fx-background-color: papayawhip;");
        tiles.setPrefColumns(5);
        tiles.setPrefRows(5);

        tiles.getChildren().add(new Tile());

        return tiles;
    }

    private ToolBar createControls(TilePane tiles) {
        Button addTile = new Button("Add Tile");
        addTile.setOnAction(action -> tiles.getChildren().add(new Tile()));

        Button removeTiles = new Button("Remove Tiles");
        removeTiles.setOnAction(action -> tiles.getChildren().clear());

        ToolBar controls = new ToolBar(addTile, removeTiles);

        controls.setMinHeight(ToolBar.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        return controls;
    }

    private class Tile extends StackPane {
        public static final int MIN_SIZE = 100;

        public Tile() {
            setStyle(
                    "-fx-background-color: " +
                            "rgb(" + random.nextInt(256) + ", " +
                            + random.nextInt(256) + ", "
                            + random.nextInt(256) + ");"
            );

            setMinSize(MIN_SIZE, MIN_SIZE);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```